# How to query for a Computed Property inside a Structured Property in GAE Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

```
class Name_score(ndb.Model): 
    def get_value_of_name(self, name, date): 
        # concatenate "X" and date before returning 
        return_text = "X"+name+str(date) 
        return return_text 

    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty() 
    name = ndb.StringProperty() 
    # Computed values 
    name_value_computed = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda e: e.get_value_of_name(e.name, e.date)) 

class Activity_db(ndb.Model): 
    # contains many properties 
    # removed the not relevant ones here 
    name_set = ndb.StructuredProperty(Name_score, repeated=True) 
    hobby = ndb.StringProperty()
```

There are many entries in the NDB. I want to get the records where on particular dates, the "name_value_computed" matches the data provided in the query.
To query for all such entries with specific "name_value_computed" and "date" value(example below), what would be the query.

Example(algorithm for condition):
    ("hobby" is "tennis") AND ((if on "date" "18/01/1900", "name_value_computed" is "XJohn18/01/1900") OR (if on "date" "22/04/1910", "name_value_computed" is "XBran22/04/1910"))
Is the below one correct:

```
date_1 = datetime.strptime("18/01/1900", '%d/%m/%Y') 
name_computed_value_1 = "XJohn18/01/1900" 
date_2 = datetime.strptime("22/04/1910", '%d/%m/%Y') 
name_computed_value_2 = "XBran22/04/1910" 
qry_1 = Activity_db.query(ndb.OR(Activity_db.name_set==Name_score(date=date_1, name_value_computed=name_computed_value_1), Activity_db.name_set==Name_score(date=date_2, name_value_computed=name_computed_value_2)), Activity_db.hobby=="tennis") 
record_list = qry_1.fetch()
```

I got the below error:

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\model.py", line 2745, in __init__

    self._set_attributes(kwds)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\model.py", line 2791, in _set_attributes

    prop._set_value(self, value)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\model.py", line 2612, in _set_value

    raise ComputedPropertyError("Cannot assign to a ComputedProperty")

ComputedPropertyError: Cannot assign to a ComputedProperty
```

I referred [this section](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#filtering_structured_properties) of the Google Python GAE page

Comment: IIRC, it should be something like `qry_1 = Activity_db.query(ndb.AND(Activity_db.name_set.date == date_1, Activity_db.name_set.name_value_computed == "nhoJ1"), Activity_db.hobby = "tennis")`.  Actually, the call to `ndb.AND` is superfluous here since all your conditions are "and"ed together...

Comment: Thanks mgilson for you reply. You correctly pointed out the unnecessary "ndb.AND" over here(removed now). My actual query contains several more conditions. But, i tried to provide a smaller version(of both class and query) of it here to only focus on the problematic part of it. 
I have tried to make my question more clear now

Comment: @mgilson Be careful with just using AND though. From the documentation an AND between two sub-properties of a repeated field do not behave as desired here, since it could match two separate properties.

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be any way to do this directly, as you can't explicitly specify the value of a computed property.

I think your best bet is to store your computed value as a `StringProperty` so that this query could work. You could replicate some of the functionality of the computed property by using a [pre-put hook](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#hooks). When you put the entity to the datastore, your hook could populate the `name_value_computed` field.

Your model would then look something like this:

```
class Name_score(ndb.Model): 
  def get_value_of_name(self, name, date): 
    # concatenate "X" and date before returning 
    return_text = "X"+name+str(date) 
    return return_text 

  def _pre_put_hook(self):
    self.name_value_computed = self.get_value_of_name(self.name, self.date)

  date = ndb.DateTimeProperty() 
  name = ndb.StringProperty() 
  # Computed values 
  name_value_computed = ndb.StringProperty()
```

You'll have to be careful that if you use this method you need to `put()` your model before accessing the `name_value_computed` field, otherwise it won't be set yet.